# How to build a Hinton diagram in python with these data

Tags: python, matplotlib, diagram

Please, I need help here =( .

I want to build with matplotlib a Hinton diagram similar to this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAmyc.gif

My data is a dictionary with 2-tuples as keys and an float as values. Ex:

`myData = {(1,1):0.0, (2,2):0.5, (3,1):1.0, (2,3):2.0}`

The first term of the tuple is the `x` position and the second is the `y` position. The value of each tuple takes a value that range from 0 to 2. The square size in the Hinton diagram represents such value.

Also, if it is possible, I want to put the X-axis values at the bottom and a bar that reference the square size with the values.

Thanks you very much!

Comment: The first google response on "matplotlib hinton diagram" is http://matplotlib.org/examples/specialty_plots/hinton_demo.html which is 80% or more of your desired solution.

Comment: Hi @HughBothwell! Yup, I saw too. But is very complex for my data. The only problem now is adjust the square size and put the bar of reference.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so far this is useful, but the square size still being a problem, as well as the bar of reference:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

myData = {(1,1):0.0, (2,2):0.5, (3,1):1.0, (2,3):2.0}
x, y, z = [], [], []

for elem in myData:
    x.append(elem[0])
    y.append(elem[1])
    z.append(myData[elem[0],elem[1]])
# Plot...
plt.scatter(x, y, s=z*10, c='black', marker='s')
plt.show()
```